# floatrow argument of \end has an extra '}'

Tags: includegraphics, floatrow, figure-placement

I'm trying to display multiple images in the same row using floatrow and ffigbox and i keep getting this error:
[image: error]

After trying to add and remove '}' i couldn't find a solution, so i would be quite happy if someone with a better understanding on the matter could help me out.

This is a snippet of my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\title{Bosch-Sensor}
\date{21/06/23}
\author{lLF}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
\begin{figure}
\centering
\floatsetup{floatrowsep=qquad}
\begin{floatrow}[2]
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{ % <-------------- this is line 19 
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}
}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: \ffigbox takes two arguments, the first should contain the caption, see the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the first mandatory argument of `\ffigbox`. Also you can not have them `.5\textwidth` and specify a `\quad` separation

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\title{Bosch-Sensor}
\date{21/06/23}
\author{lLF}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
\begin{figure}
\centering
\floatsetup{floatrowsep=qquad}
\begin{floatrow}[2]
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{capt1}}{%
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}
}%
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{capt2}}{% <-------------- this is line 19 
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}
}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works!  I did not really catch that the captions were mandatory. Also why it is not supposed to work with .5? i just tried and it actually does work

Comment: @FerroLuca you get an overfull box warning and it overlaps the right margin as if both images are half textwidth and they have 1em space between them, then the total width is 1em more than textwidth

Comment: @FerroLuca you do not have to have a caption but the argument is mandatory, so you could replace `{\caption{capt1}}` by `{}`

Comment: perfect, so the total sum of the dimension should never be exactly equal to 1 but a a safety margin less

Comment: @FerroLuca well you can do an exact version if for example you have 10pt gap you can make them `\dimexpr.5\textwidth - 5pt`  so it all adds up